# usingとfor文を使った複数ファイルアップロード

Tags: c#

1枚の画像をアップロードし、返ってきたデータを受信するまでできました。
しかし、複数しようとなると中々できませんでした。
単純にfor文をかけているのですが、どのようにすればよろしいでしょうか？
lines.lengthは画像の数です。
サーバは画像を1枚アップするごとに一つのXMLデータを返します。

```
// ローカル画像ディレクトリ
string img = dirResize;

// ブログAtompubAPIルートエンドURL
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create
    ("https://aaa/atompub/atomrootend");

req.Method = "POST";
req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "WSSE profile='UsernameToke'");
req.Headers.Add("X-WSSE", wsseHeader());
req.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
req.Timeout = 20000;

// ローカル画像をサーバにアップロード
using (Stream dataStream = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    for(int i = 0; i<lines.Length; i++)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream
              (img+"\\"+(i+1)+".jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            fs.CopyTo(dataStream);
        }
    }
}

//サーバーからの応答を受信するためのWebResponseを取得
HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

//応答データを受信するためのStreamを取得
Stream resStream = res.GetResponseStream();

//受信して表示
StreamReader sr =
    new StreamReader(resStream, enc);

// 受信するデータはXML形式
string content = sr.ReadToEnd();
xdoc.LoadXml(content);

// XMLにある画像ソースの画像URLだけを抽出
collect(xdoc, "content", "src", (val) => Console.WriteLine(val));
Console.WriteLine("content = " + content);
```

例えば2枚アップロードした時、この表示が正解
content = http://example.com/img/1.jpg
content = http://example.com/img/2.jpg

現在はこう
content = http://example.com/img/2.jpg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1つのリクエストについて、`lines`で指定されるファイルを連結して1度に送信するコードになっています。おそらく意図したものでは無いでしょう。

おそらく1リクエストにつき1ファイルを送信するものでしょうから、`for`ループがこのコード全体を囲む形になっている必要があります。

```
for(int i = 0; i<lines.Length; i++)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream
      (img+"\\"+(i+1)+".jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create
            ("https://aaa/atompub/atomrootend");

        using (Stream dataStream = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            fs.CopyTo(dataStream);
        }

        HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

        Console.WriteLine("content = " + content);
    }
}
```

Comment: using filestreamの上にforを乗せると『型 'System.ObjectDisposedException' のハンドルされていない例外が mscorlib.dll で発生しました』とエラーになります。

Comment: suzukisさんの記述は正しいですしそのようなエラーは発生しません。まめたろうさんが書き写す際に誤ったか、挙げられていない部分で問題となる処理を加えているかだと思います。

Comment: 出来ました、私が間違っていました。本当に助かりました。